# ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'magnific-popup') on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am working on `Rails 3.2.17` where facing issue on `Heroku` when pushed code. It is working fine in local.

Actually, application already working fine on Heroku but after some changes pushed then show me error which I tried lots but not find proper solutions.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'magnific-popup'
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339935+00:00 app[web.2]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:2)):
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339936+00:00 app[web.2]:     69:     = favicon_link_tag "travelshopa_Pin_SM_Icon-01_big.png"
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339937+00:00 app[web.2]:     70:     meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339938+00:00 app[web.2]:     71:     meta name="p:domain_verify" content="8190160645e8dabcaa234d75587f59aa"
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339939+00:00 app[web.2]:     72:     = content_for?(:stylesheet) ? yield(:stylesheet) : stylesheet_link_tag('application')
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339939+00:00 app[web.2]:     73:     / = stylesheet_link_tag "print", media: "print"
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339940+00:00 app[web.2]:     74:     = csrf_meta_tag
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339941+00:00 app[web.2]:     75:     script src="//cdn.mouseflow.com/projects/905e8269-8408-434b-9f68-cb0a2847579c.js" async=""
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339942+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:72:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_slim__1613734431592662227_70052446378020'
2016-11-04T13:31:33.339942+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/main_controller.rb:36:in `new_home'
```

I precomplied already on Heroku manytimes but still not solved it.

Anyone have a idea then share it.

Thanks

Comment: Try to run application on local in production mode

Comment: Have you tried these commands before deployment?: 

`bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear`
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

# Check if something is broken
`bundle exec rake test`

.. Push all the changes to remote repository...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found out that issue regarding some cache configuration enable in production.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue.

Issue was `cache setting enable in production.rb file` which generated issue.

Thanks for view and try to answer me.